# Fetching hierarchical data in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

I have some data structured as Country/State/District/PostalCode stored as columns in table called "LocationData" in Cassandra with Postal code as partition key/primary key. I have a front-end where I am trying to fetch these details and show them in a select tag. When a user selects a country(dynamically loaded), that country's states will be dynamically loaded in another select tag. When the user selects a state, that state's districts will be loaded dynamically and the same with the postal code.

Problem is that when I try to query all distinct countries available in the database like `"SELECT DISTINCT country FROM tableName"`, it shows an error since DISTINCT keyword can be used only on partition keys. So I have to use `"SELECT country FROM tableName"` which will give thousands of rows since country column value will be the same for a lot of postal codes. Then I take the result set from the query and get all distinct countries programmatically. Similarly, when a user selects a country I fetch all states of that country using `SELECT state FROM tableName where country=" SomeCountry"` which also gives duplicates entries that needs to be filtered to get all distinct states which is grossly inefficient since I have to search through thousands of rows to get distinct values every time the user selects a different country/state/district etc.

How should I change the structure of the table so I can query database in this hierarchical fashion?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to write as a comment but it is longer than it.

I think Cassandra is overkill for this. Your data structure is almost perfect match for RDBMS + additional cache layer. You have relations(foreign keys), need joins(sometimes multi level) and you may use `Common Table Expressions` for hierarchical data. Almost every modern RDBMs support this. [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) or [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). These numbers are almost constant for country, state, district etc.

I don't think you need to "horizontally" scale it, the volume is almost constant, you may reduce the load with additional cache replicas if needed. you may keep cached data in Redis using `lists` or `hashes` to not hit the database regularly for constant data.

Comment: You are right. But I have another table with the columns PostalCode/TimeStamp/Value/ValueType. Postalcode is the partition key and Timestamp is the clustering key. I get real-time data and insert those into this table. Since it's time-series I'm using Cassandra. Though the other table is a great candidate for RDBMS, I'm not sure whether keeping the data in two different data bases is a good idea. So I wanted to know how can I change the structure of the table 'LocationData' so I can query database in hierarchical fashion

Comment: It is useful to keep data to "best matched database", but comes with the tradeoffs (in my company we have 9 different databases for different purposes). Maintaining multiple databases, cost, development etc. @yash